# Database entry streak in mysql/mariadb - until today

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, gaps-and-islands, mariadb-10.1

I asked this question yesterday, but I didn't make it clear enough as it seems, so I'm gonna add some information to make everything clear.

Consider the following 2 tables:

```
0_12_table

ID userID text timestamp
1  1      bla  2020-08-07 10:30:00
2  1      blub 2020-08-06 11:30:00
3  1      abc  2020-08-05 09:20:00
4  1      def  2020-08-04 06:13:00
5  2      ghi  2020-08-02 08:05:00
6  2      abc  2020-08-05 10:20:00
7  3      def  2020-08-04 07:13:00
8  4      ghi  2020-08-02 09:05:00
9  5      jkl  2020-08-07 06:30:00
10 5      mno  2020-08-08 08:32:00

12_24_table:

ID userID text timestamp
1  1      bla  2020-08-07 19:30:00
2  1      blub 2020-08-06 21:30:00
3  1      abc  2020-08-05 19:20:00
4  2      def  2020-08-04 16:13:00
5  2      ghi  2020-08-02 18:05:00
6  2      abc  2020-08-05 20:20:00
7  3      def  2020-08-04 17:13:00
8  4      ghi  2020-08-02 19:05:00
9  5      jkl  2020-08-07 20:13:00
```

Basically, users can (and are animated to do so) to add one entry in the databse between 00:00 and 12:00 and one between 12:01 and 23:59.

Now I'd like to reward them for adding consecutive entries. Whenever they miss their timeframe, that "counter" is reset to 0 though...

In the above given data, the user with the userID 1 would have a streak of 3 days right now (in my time, its 9 AM right now), whenever its after 12 AM though, and he didn't make another entry, the counter would be set to 0 and the streak is over, because he missed adding an entry for the morning.

The users with the userID's 2,3 and 4 would have no streak at all. The streak is always cancelled, when there is one morning entry or evening entry missing.

The user with the userID 5 would have a streak of 1, which would increased to 2, whenever he made his entry for the timeframe of 12:01 to 23:59.

I hope you understand the logic. The important part is, that it does NOT matter, if he had a streak of 10 2 days ago. Whenever there is an entry missing, the streak is reset to 0. So when there is no entry until 12 AM on one day for the morning table or when there is no entry for the evening until 23:59, then the streak is gone. It always uses today as reference, so its really "consecutive entries until today".

The answer that seems to be as close as I got so far is the following:

```
select min(dte), max(dte), count(*)
from (select dte, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select dte
            from ((select date(timestamp) as dte, 1 as morning, 0 as evening
                   from morning
                  ) union all
                  (select date(timestamp) as dte, 0 as morning, 1 as evening
                   from evening
                  )
                 ) me
            group by dte
            having sum(morning) > 0 and sum(evening) > 0
            order by dte
           ) d cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) me
group by dte - interval seqnum day
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

However, I didn't introduce the userID there so far and the biggest problem: It just takes the last streak, no matter if there is a gap until today.. But, as mentioned, it always takes today as reference.

I hope someone can help me here.

Last important information: I'm using MariaDB 10.1.45, so "WITH" or "ROWNUM()" is not available, updating is not possible right now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would really be simpler in a more recent version that uses window functions.  But you can adapt the variables to get *all* streaks for users:

```
select userid, count(*) as length
from (select dte, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select dte
            from ((select userid, date(timestamp) as dte, 1 as morning, 0 as evening
                   from morning
                  ) union all
                  (select userid, date(timestamp) as dte, 0 as morning, 1 as evening
                   from evening
                  )
                 ) me
            group by userid, dte
            having sum(morning) > 0 and sum(evening) > 0
            order by userid, dte
           ) d cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) me
group by userid, dte - interval seqnum day
order by count(*) desc;
```

It turns out that a "global" sequence works as well as local sequences for this problem, so the variable use is still simple.  The changes are to the `group by` and `order by` clauses.

You can then use this as a subquery to get the maximum:

```
select userid, max(seq)
from (select userid, count(*) as seq
      from (select dte, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
            from (select dte
                  from ((select userid, date(timestamp) as dte, 1 as morning, 0 as evening
                         from morning
                        ) union all
                        (select userid, date(timestamp) as dte, 0 as morning, 1 as evening
                         from evening
                        )
                       ) me
                  group by userid, dte
                  having sum(morning) > 0 and sum(evening) > 0
                  order by userid, dte
                 ) d cross join
                 (select @rn := 0) params
           ) me
      group by userid, dte - interval seqnum day
     ) u
group by userid;
```

Note:  Users with no streaks would be filtered out.  You can put them back in using a `left join` in the outer query.  However, you would really want a table of all *users* for this, rather than your two separate tables, so I haven't bothered.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.. unfortunately, result is still not correct... I tried it with my table and I got 2 as result, where it should be 0, because user didn't add an entry last day... Also added `userid` few times in the select statements

Comment: see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7ac9200b3ec469a5bba5968a6c607ae

and compare it to my descirptions above... users still have a streak, even without entries...

Comment: also, whn doing some changes, it does strange things, in this case, userID 2 has 2 occurences in the result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39586680e2471ef2d7e5e8a453fcf443